# Error message "homing failed printer halted please reset"

Tags: homing, reset

I have an Ender 3 Pro 4.2.7  2.0.8.2 that I haven't used for a couple of months; switched it on, all perfect. I tried to print a model and the PLA wouldn't stick to the bed; I think the hotend was a fraction high.

Re-adjusted bed to ensure square and flat as hadn't been used. Switched off and then hotend defaulted to 5 mm above table. Thought I'd do a firmware update, load the latest software put, it on a clean, formatted (4096) SD card, switch off power put the card in, and switch it on, just booted up as normal, ignoring the firmware update.

I followed all instructions from the web including a new card, renaming the file, etc. Switched off, switched on. now when I try to do **Auto Home** or **Level Bed**, **nothing** happens, no beeps no movement, and a minute later get "Homing failed printer halted please reset". Check all connections, put a meter on all micro switches, and perfect.

Nothing now moves and don't know what to do.

Comment: "Switched off, switched on" -- make sure you don't have a USB cable plugged in during the power cycle, otherwise you're not fully "off."

Answer (score 1):

Check if the firmware is for the board version of your printer. Different boards may have different drivers or pin definition, which happens for example, when you flash a 4.2.2 firmware on a 4.2.7 board and vice versa.

Comment: Yes have checked, As I said, I tried to update to latest firmware, loaded SD card as per instructions, switched off printer, left for at least 30sec, put in SD card with .bin update but printer ignores card and just boots up as normal (with fault)

Comment: Rename the firmware to something like F123.bin